# Resizing a UISegmentedControl within a UIToolBar with constraints for different screen sizes

Tags: swift, swift2, uisegmentedcontrol, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I have a `UIToolBar` underneath a navbar, and in this toolbar is a Bar Buttom Item which holds a `UISegmentedControl`. The problem is I can't add constraints to anything inside the toolbar. The `UISegmentedControl` pins itself to the left margin when I place it inside the toolbar/bar button item, but then I don't get any dashed blue line when I try to set it width to be the same from the margin on the right side. I see no options to center either, but I don't really want to center, I want to make the segmented control grow in width as the screen goes from iPhone4 to iPhone6+ (in portrait) so that its always some X-pts from the left and right margin. How can I go about doing this?

I have the width of the toolbar, which is 375 for a 4.7inch screen. I can also get the width of the segmented control for this size too, but I can't tell the correct width to make the margins on the left and right the same, I can only eyeball it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `UISegmentedControl` as a direct subview to the `UIToolbar` (either via `addSubview` or directly in interface builder). While going the detour around `UIBarButtonItem` seems convenient here, it deprives you of the possibility to lay things out exactly as wanted, because `UIToolbar` will handle layout for you and you cannot override this.
When you add the `UISegmentedControl` as a subview, you can add constraints as needed to make it fill the entire width.